# Making Google Calendar add-ons

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am wanting to develop a Google Calendar add-on so that all the people in my group will automatically have all of our meeting dates added to their calendar but I can not find any documentation on developing Google Calendar add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, developing Google Calendar add-ons is not yet possible. 
You can eventually use a Chrome Extension and modify it to your liking.

For more information, you can read this:

1. [Is it possible to develop an add-on for Google Calendar?](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/10594701?hl=en)
2. [Chrome Extension Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

If that does not solve your issue, I suggest you filing a Feature Request on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com).